# "Married Women & Schoolgirls"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In my youth a wise man offered the following advice:

> "There are two kinds of women whom you should avoid: married and schoolgirls (teenagers)".

How is this warning to be expressed, in Latin? Here's a guess based on the "CAVE-CANEM" model ("House of the Tragic Poet", Pompeii) using imperative, "cave", plus accusative.

> "cave duo genera feminarum quae sunt declinari: nuptae et discipulae.".

> "Beware of two kinds of women who are to be avoided: married and schoolgirls."

There does not appear to be a Latin word for "teenager"; but, then, young people were not considered to be of any import in Roman society. Further, the Latin-equivalent suffix, (-"decim") is a part of 12 ("duodecim") but not a part of 19 ("undeviginti"). Such a noun, had it existed, might have been, "deciomor/a, wouldn't it?

The advice is still sound:

> "....nuptae et 'decimorae'."

(There is a Latin word, "decimor" = "I am decimated", first-person passive of verb, "decimo". There is a grim irony, here, for men who have got involved with the wrong women--but that's beyond the scope of this Q.)

How would this counsel have been expressed, in Latin?

Comment: I'm not sure whether girls went to school.

Comment: @Cerberus: No, I don't believe they did. I searched for an equivalent of "teenager" which would have been better. How about "adulescentes"? The age-range in this term is approx. 14-21 (Wiki) which covers some, if not all of the sentiment.

Comment: you can have a look at [Orbis Pictoris](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/28299/28299-h/28299-h.htm) p.45 (picture 37), it seems you should go for *puella* if I to judge by the picture